# Gmod 13 Lua Error

Tags: lua, garrys-mod

I am trying to learn Lua and I decided that for my first project I would try to fix a broken script. I have fixed a few of the bugs but I'm stuck now. Can you help me?

```
    function SWEP:PrimaryAttack()
     if( CurTime() < self.NextStrike ) then return; end
     self.Weapon:EmitSound("player/skick/sparta.mp3")
     self.NextStrike = ( CurTime() + 3.5 );
     timer.Simple( 1.80, function() self:AttackAnim() end)
                        -Next line broken-
         timer.Simple( 2.40, function() self.Weapon:SendWeaponAnim( ACT_VM_IDLE ) end);
     timer.Simple( 2.00, function() self.ShootBullets( self ) end)
     self.Owner:SetAnimation( PLAYER_ATTACK1 );
end 

function SWEP:ShootBullets()
    -Next line Broken-
         local trace =Owner:GetEyeTrace();
    if trace.HitPos:Distance(self.Owner:GetShootPos()) <= 130 then
        if( trace.Entity:IsPlayer() or trace.Entity:IsNPC() or trace.Entity:GetClass()=="prop_ragdoll" ) then
                timer.Simple(0, game.ConsoleCommand, "host_timescale 0.1\n")
                timer.Simple(0.5, game.ConsoleCommand, "host_timescale 1\n")
            self.Owner:EmitSound( self.FleshHit[math.random(1,#self.FleshHit)] );
        else
            self.Owner:EmitSound( self.Hit[math.random(1,#self.Hit)] );
        end
                bullet = {}
                bullet.Num    = 5
                bullet.Src    = self.Owner:GetShootPos()
                bullet.Dir    = self.Owner:GetAimVector()
                bullet.Spread = Vector(0.04, 0.04, 0.04)
                bullet.Tracer = 0
                bullet.Force  = 250
                bullet.Damage = 1000000
            self.Owner:FireBullets(bullet)
    end
```

I'm getting an error saying `Attempting to index field 'Weapon' (a nil value)`.
Can anyone explain how to fix this?

Im not allowed to post imagesthis is what im getting [Error image](http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/9093/74855130.png)

Comment: I love GMOD, best of luck dude!

Comment: You can use `self:AttackAnim()` instead of `self.AttackAnim(self)`. That's the whole point of the colon (**:**). Are you sure it doesn't crash earlier, when the `Weapon` field is used for the first time?

Comment: Thanks ill give that a try but no idea why i would b getting that error?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting that error is that "Weapon" (specifically self.Weapon) was not initialized. self.Weapon points to nothing, so you can't call any functions on it.

Can you show us the lines that the error messages reference? It looks like the file is `shared.lua`, lines 84, 85 and 90. The surrounding code would be helpful, too. I'm guessing that you posted it as part of your original question, but it's not helpful without any line numbers!